# trouble using Python super

Tags: python, super

So I'm currently learning Python's basics, using the book Python Crash Course.
I'm on the chapter about classes, more precisely on the sub-class part of it.
So first up, here's my code:

```
class Car():
"""une representation simpliste de voiture"""

def __init__(self, constructeur, annee, modele):
    self.constructeur = constructeur
    self.modele = modele
    self.annee = annee
    self.odometer_reading = 0

def descriptive_name(self):
    long_name = str(self.annee) + ' ' + self.constructeur + ' ' + self.modele
    return long_name.title()

def update_odometer(self, mileage):
    """set odometer reading"""

    if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
        self.odometer_reading = mileage
    else:
        print("You can't roll back and odometer!\n")

def increment_odometer(self, miles):
    self.odometer_reading += miles

def read_odometer(self):
    """print mileage"""
    print("this car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.\n")
class ElectricCar(Car):
def __init__(self, constructeur, annee, modele):
    super().__init__(constructeur, annee, modele)
    pass
my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
```

So, with this code I get this error message:

> super().**init**(constructeur, annee, modele)
>   TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

The code I use is the same as in the book (except the french part, that are in english in the book).
I tried with and without the "pass" of the "super()" and tried giving "super" the arguments "self" and "Car".

I'm using Python 3 and I'm on linux.

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: `super` behaves differently between Python 2 and Python 3. Which version are you using? The tutorial is probably designed to work with Python 3.

Comment: ... And you should definitely be learning Python 3 if you are just starting to learn Python, unless you have a good reason to be learning Python 2 (for example, your job requires it, or you want to contribute to a code-base that is written in Python 2)

Comment: I just edited as you asked :)
I'm using Python 3

Comment: You think you're on Python 3, but you're probably not. You may have multiple Python versions installed.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are on Python 3? At the top of your code, put `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: oh yeah I'm sorry, my editor switched to the Python 2 build system and I hadn't noticed it ^^"

thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super() syntax is Python 3
If you're still using Python 2, you need super(ElectricCar, self)